# Find a vertex cover of size 20 for the pictured graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to use Konig's theorem to show that the pictured graph $G$ has no perfect matching. By this theorem it suffices to find a vertex cover of size $|G|/2-1= 20$, but so far I have only been able to find vertex covers of size 21. I'm just doing this by inspection as opposed to using any algorithms, and it's not immediately obvious to me how to find a cover of size 20.

[image]

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt My apologies. Is it alright to copy and paste the title as the first line of the body of the text?

Comment: Ofc its alright, though while you're at it, you may wish to include some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/272831) behind your question to avoid its being closed for that reason. This may include explaining what you've tried or what's holding you back from solving this problem yourself. (more info. in link)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to just stumble around blindly until you get there, here's how you find the solution.

The solution you found with $21$ vertices probably looks something like this:

[image: Naive solution]

If this is the optimal solution, then there is a perfect matching in which every edge has one endpoint among the chosen vertices. But in fact, if we try to find such a matching, we get irreparably stuck:

[image: Naive solution gets stuck]

We started by giving a bunch of vertices an edge, but the purple vertex has no edge to an unused neighbor. There's no way to fix this, because the $11$ vertices we've looked at so far (the $10$ we've given an edge, plus the purple vertex) have only $10$ neighbors... but that's exactly what we want to improve the vertex cover. Just replace these $11$ vertices by their $10$ neighbors, and you get a solution of size $20$:

[image: Improved solution]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Must write at least $30$ charcters.

[image]

Comment: Aha, thank you very much!